# Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer (Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, meteor

I am getting this error. I am trying to make a search criteria, this search criteria works with other modules I am working on but in this specific module, I am not sure as to why I am encountering this error

```
(through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl[\"content\"]->
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->
com.meteor.coral.portfolio.modules.client.domain.Client[\"membershipTypeId\"]->
com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.codes.domain.CodeValue_$$_jvstb7f_65[\"handler\"])"
```

This is my Entity class (I just removed some long methods of codes)
I have seen some solutions where they put `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` but I do not know where exactly should I put it. Help me with this thank you

**This is my Client.java class**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.codes.data.CodeValueData;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.codes.domain.CodeValue;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.core.api.JsonCommand;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.core.data.ApiParameterError;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.core.data.DataValidatorBuilder;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.core.domain.AbstractPersistableCustom;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.core.exception.PlatformApiDataValidationException;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.core.service.DateUtils;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.documentmanagement.domain.Image;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.infrastructure.security.service.RandomPasswordGenerator;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.agentreferror.domain.AgentReferror;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.membershipsubtyperegular.domain.MembershipSubTypeRegular;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.office.domain.Office;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.rankandserviceclass.domain.RankAndServiceClass;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.relationshipandreverse.domain.RelationshipAndReverse;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.staff.domain.Staff;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.organization.unitcode.domain.UnitCode;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.common.useradministration.domain.AppUser;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.modules.client.constants.ClientApiConstants;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.modules.group.domain.Group;
import com.meteor.coral.portfolio.modules.paymenttype.domain.PaymentType;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "m_client", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "account_no" }, name = "account_no_UNIQUE"), //
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "mobile_no" }, name = "mobile_no_UNIQUE") })
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public final class Client extends BaseCoralModel {

    //added by Rob
    @Column(name = "memberno", length = 20, nullable = true)
    private String memberno;
    
    @Column(name = "account_no", length = 20, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String accountNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "office_id", nullable = false)
    private Office office;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transfer_to_office_id", nullable = true)
    private Office transferToOffice;

    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id", nullable = true)
    private Image image;

    /**
     * A value from {@link ClientStatus}.
     */
    @Column(name = "status_enum", nullable = false)
    private Integer status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_status", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue subStatus;
    
    @Column(name = "activation_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date activationDate;

    @Column(name = "office_joining_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date officeJoiningDate;

    @Column(name = "firstname", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "middlename", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String middlename;

    @Column(name = "lastname", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "fullname", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String fullname;

    @Column(name = "display_name", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name = "mobile_no", length = 50, nullable = true, unique = true)
    private String mobileNo;
    
    @Column(name = "email_address", length = 50, unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "is_staff", nullable = false)
    private boolean isStaff;

    @Column(name = "external_id", length = 100, nullable = true, unique = true)
    private String externalId;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gender_cv_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue gender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id")
    private Staff staff;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "m_group_client", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    private Set<Group> groups;

    @Transient
    private boolean accountNumberRequiresAutoGeneration = false;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "closure_reason_cv_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue closureReason;

    @Column(name = "closedon_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date closureDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reject_reason_cv_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue rejectionReason;

    @Column(name = "rejectedon_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date rejectionDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rejectedon_userid", nullable = true)
    private AppUser rejectedBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "withdraw_reason_cv_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue withdrawalReason;

    @Column(name = "withdrawn_on_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date withdrawalDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "withdraw_on_userid", nullable = true)
    private AppUser withdrawnBy;

    @Column(name = "reactivated_on_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date reactivateDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reactivated_on_userid", nullable = true)
    private AppUser reactivatedBy;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "closedon_userid", nullable = true)
    private AppUser closedBy;

    @Column(name = "submittedon_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date submittedOnDate;

//    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "submittedon_userid", nullable = true)
//    private AppUser submittedBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_on", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date updatedOnDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by", nullable = true)
    private AppUser updatedBy;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "activatedon_userid", nullable = true)
    private AppUser activatedBy;

    @Column(name = "default_savings_product", nullable = true)
    private Long savingsProductId;
    
    @Column(name = "default_savings_account", nullable = true)
    private Long savingsAccountId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_type_cv_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue clientType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_classification_cv_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue clientClassification;
    
    @Column(name = "legal_form_enum", nullable = true)
    private Integer legalForm;

    @Column(name = "reopened_on_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date reopenedDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reopened_by_userid", nullable = true)
    private AppUser reopenedBy;
    
    @Column(name = "proposed_transfer_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date proposedTransferDate;
    
    
    
    
    //***additional fields for membership
    //***
    //***
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "membership_type_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue membershipTypeId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_place_code_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue sourcePlaceCodeId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rank_and_service", nullable = false)
    private RankAndServiceClass rankAndService;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_status_Id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue memberStatusId;
    
    private String qualifier;

    
    private boolean isChaplain;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "membership_sub_type_id", nullable = false)
    private MembershipSubTypeRegular membershipSubTypeId;
    
    private String overrideReason;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "override_by")
    private AppUser overrideBy;

    private String mothersMaidenName;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "family_group_identifier_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue familyGroupIdentifierId;
    
    private String badgeNo;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_code", nullable = true)
    private UnitCode unitCode;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employer_id", nullable = true)
    private CodeValue employerId;

    private String natureOfWork;
    
    private String tin;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date regularizationDate;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employment_status_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue employmentStatusId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employment_industry_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue employmentIndustryId;

    private String employmentName;

    private String employmentPhoneNo;
    
    private String riskRating;

    private boolean pep;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nationality_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue nationalityId;
    
    
    private boolean muslim;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "civil_status_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue civilStatusId;
    
    private String placeOfBirth;

    private String phoneNo;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "payment_type_id", nullable = false)
    private PaymentType paymentTypeId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "filing_mode_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue filingMode;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_referror_code_id", nullable = true)
    private AgentReferror agentReferrorCodeId;

    
    private boolean psslaiTosri;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sources_of_funds_wealth_id", nullable = false)
    private CodeValue sourcesOfFundsWealthId;
    
    private String memberpan;
    
    private String memberpin;
    
    private String bosEmployeeNo;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "relationship_id", nullable = true)
    private RelationshipAndReverse relationshipId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "principal_member")
    private Client principalMember;
    
    
    private boolean mentallyIncapacitated;

}
```

**This is my CodeValue.java class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "m_code_value", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "code_id", "code_value" }, name = "code_value_duplicate") })
public class CodeValue extends AbstractPersistableCustom<Long> {

  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5671149962262010193L;

    @Column(name = "code_value", length = 100)
    private String label;

    @Column(name = "order_position")
    private int position;

    @Column(name = "code_description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "code_id", nullable = false)
    private Code code;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean isActive;
    
    @Column(name = "is_mandatory")
    private boolean mandatory;

    public static CodeValue createNew(final Code code, final String label, final int position, final String description,
            final boolean isActive, final boolean mandatory) {
        return new CodeValue(code, label, position, description, isActive, mandatory);
    }

    protected CodeValue() {
        //
    }

    private CodeValue(final Code code, final String label, final int position, final String description, 
            final boolean isActive, final boolean mandatory) {
        this.code = code;
        this.label = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(label, null);
        this.position = position;
        this.description = description;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    public String label() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public int position() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public static CodeValue fromJson(final Code code, final JsonCommand command) {

        final String label = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.NAME.getValue());
        Integer position = command.integerValueSansLocaleOfParameterNamed(CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.POSITION.getValue());
        String description = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.DESCRIPTION.getValue());
        Boolean isActiveObj = command.booleanObjectValueOfParameterNamed(CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.IS_ACTIVE.getValue());
        boolean isActive = true;
        if (isActiveObj != null) {
            isActive = isActiveObj;
        }
        if (position == null) {
            position = new Integer(0);
        }
        
        Boolean mandatory = command.booleanPrimitiveValueOfParameterNamed(
                CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.IS_MANDATORY.getValue());
        
        // if the "mandatory" Boolean object is null, then set it to false by default
        if (mandatory == null) {
            mandatory = false;
        }
        
        return new CodeValue(code, label, position.intValue(), description, isActive, mandatory);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> update(final JsonCommand command) {

        final Map<String, Object> actualChanges = new LinkedHashMap<>(2);

        final String labelParamName = CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.NAME.getValue();
        if (command.isChangeInStringParameterNamed(labelParamName, this.label)) {
            final String newValue = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(labelParamName);
            actualChanges.put(labelParamName, newValue);
            this.label = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(newValue, null);
        }

        final String decriptionParamName = CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.DESCRIPTION.getValue();
        if (command.isChangeInStringParameterNamed(decriptionParamName, this.description)) {
            final String newValue = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(decriptionParamName);
            actualChanges.put(decriptionParamName, newValue);
            this.description = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(newValue, null);
        }

        final String positionParamName = CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.POSITION.getValue();
        if (command.isChangeInIntegerSansLocaleParameterNamed(positionParamName, this.position)) {
            final Integer newValue = command.integerValueSansLocaleOfParameterNamed(positionParamName);
            actualChanges.put(positionParamName, newValue);
            this.position = newValue.intValue();
        }

        final String isActiveParamName = CODEVALUE_JSON_INPUT_PARAMS.IS_ACTIVE.getValue();
        if (command.isChangeInBooleanParameterNamed(isActiveParamName, this.isActive)) {
            final Boolean newValue = command.booleanPrimitiveValueOfParameterNamed(isActiveParamName);
            actualChanges.put(isActiveParamName, newValue);
            this.isActive = newValue.booleanValue();
        }

        return actualChanges;
    }

    public CodeValueData toData() {
        return CodeValueData.instance(getId(), this.label, this.position, this.isActive, this.mandatory);
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I trigger the button
[image: This is what I get when I trigger the button]

Comment: Could you please provide **full** stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Add @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) above all entity classes name.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows when parsing the `membershipTypeId` field, so you can try to add this field to the `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

Comment: I tried to do this, I am not sure if this is what you are trying to say, sorry I am not expert @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "membership_type_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    private CodeValue membershipTypeId;

Comment: Hello @PaulineMartino, you could place the @JsonIgnoreProperties on class level, for example: 
`@JsonIgnoreProperties({"membershipTypeId"})
public final class Client extends BaseCoralModel {}`

But, please noticed that use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` will ignore your property data when parsing to JSON

Comment: Ok I tried to implement your suggestion, then I encountered this error: Could not write JSON: Direct self-reference leading to cycle; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle

Comment: I saw you have a property `private Client principalMember`, it's a `Client` data type also. I think it is the reason because it makes an infinity loop when parsing. Could you please ignore this field also?